# Unit Testing URL Parameters in Swift

Tags: swift, url, tdd

I am trying to unit a `URL` in Swift by using TDD. I want to ensure that the `URL` is equal to the expected `URL`. I am using a `Router` `enum`, using `Alamofire`, to create my `URL`s. So, as property of the `Router` `enum`, I have a `Dictionary<String,String>?` property because I may not need parameters for other `URL`s. However, I do need parameters for the authentication `URL`.

The `parameters` `Dictionary<String,String>?` follows:

```swift
internal enum Router: URLConvertible {

    internal static let baseURLString = "https://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx"

    case authentication(clientID: String)

}

extension Router {

    var pathString: String {
        switch self {
            case .authentication: return "xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxx"
        }
    }

    var method: HTTPMethod {
        switch self {
            case .authentication: return .get
        }
    }

    var parameters: Dictionary<String, String>? {
        switch self {
            case .authentication(let clientID): return ["xxxxx": "xxxx", "client_id": clientID]
        }
    }

    func asURL() throws -> URL {
        switch self {
            case .authentication:
               return URL(string: "https://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxx?xxxxx=xxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx")!
        }
    }

}
```

I have been able to successfully code everything the TDD way up to this point. Where I am stuck is testing the returned `URL`. Since `parameters` is of type `Dictionary<String,String>?`, I want to iterate `parameters` by using the following logic:

```swift
var parametersStringArray = Array<Dictionary<String,String>>()

for (key, value) in parameters {
    // Create a parameter string from each set
    // Something like the following:
    let parameterString = String(describing: \(key)=\(value))
    parametersStringArray.append(parameterString)
}

let parametersString = parametersStringArray.joined(separator: "&")
let fullURLString = baseURLString + "?\(parametersString)"
return URL(string: fullURLString)!
```

By creating the parameters like this, when I test the expected `URL` against the returned `URL` from the `Router` `enum` in `asURL() throws -> URL`, it could fail part of the time since the parameters are added to the `URL` string without an expected order. In other words, If my expected URL is `https://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx?xxxxx=xxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx`, it could either match or fail by returning the parameters in the reverse order, like so: `https://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx?client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&xxxxx=xxxx`.

Is there a better solution for me testing the `URL`s to ensure that the correct `URL` is returned when the parameters can be in any order since they are added to the `URL`'s string when iterating them?

Should I create two `URL`s with the parameters both ways and match against either? The reason that I don't see that being appropriate is because the more parameters you have, the more `URL`s you have to create to test against.

My current tests for testing the `URL` for authentication follow:

```swift
import XCTest
import Alamofire
@testable import Projects

class AuthenticationURLTests: XCTestCase {

    func test_API_BaseURLString_IsCorrect() {
        let baseURLString = Router.baseURLString
        let expectedBaseURLString = "https://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx/"
        XCTAssertEqual(baseURLString, expectedBaseURLString, "Base URL does not match expected base URL. Expected base URLs to match.")
    }

    func test_API_OAuthPath_IsCorrect() {
        let pathString = Router.authentication(clientID: "xxxxxxxxxx").pathString
        let expectedPathString = "xxxxx/xxxxx/xxxxxxxxx"
        XCTAssertEqual(pathString, expectedPathString, "Path string does not match expected path string. Expected path strings to match.")
    }

    func test_API_OAuthMethod_IsCorrect() {
        let method = Router.authentication(clientID: "xxxxxxxxxx").method
        let expectedMethod = HTTPMethod.get
        XCTAssertEqual(method, expectedMethod, "HTTP methods do not match. Expected HTTP methods to match.")
    }

    func test_API_OAuth_ParametersContainsKeyForXXXXX() {
        let scopeString = Router.authentication(clientID: "xxxxxxxxxx").parameters?["xxxxx"]
        let expectedScopeString = "xxxx"
        XCTAssertEqual(scopeString, expectedScopeString, "Scope strings do not match. Expected scope strings to match.")
    }

    func test_API_OAuth_ParametersContainsKeyForClientID() {
        let clientID = Router.authentication(clientID: "12345abcde").parameters?["client_id"]
        let expectedClientID_Fake = "12345abcde"
        XCTAssertEqual(clientID, expectedClientID_Fake, "Client IDs do not match. Expected client IDs to match.")
    }

    func test_API_OAuth_URLIsCorrect() {
        do {
            let url = try Router.authentication(clientID: "12345abcde").asURL()
            // Here, I want to ensure that the `URL`s match:
            let expectedURL = URL(string: https://xxx.xxxxxx.xxx?xxxxx=xxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxxx)!
        } catch { XCTFail("Could not create URL for OAuth") }
    }

}
```

Sorry for all of the `x`s within the provided code. I wanted to ensure that I didn't provide any information regarding my client's application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`URLComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcomponents).

This class is very handy to manipulate URLs. It can for example be [initialized using a `URL` instance](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcomponents/1780039-init), and then list all the query parameters in an array via the [`queryItems` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/urlcomponents/1779966-queryitems).

> Where I am stuck is testing the returned `URL`.

`URLComponents` also conforms to `Equatable`, so you could test that the returned URL value is what you expect like this:

1. Create a `URLComponents` instance configured with all the parameters you are expecting. This is the *arrange* part of your test.
2. Get the value of your URL via your `asURL()` method. This is the *act* part of your test.
3. Create a new `URLComponents` instance using the `URL` value you just got, and then compare it with the `URLComponents` built using the expected values, via `XCTAssertEqual` for example. This is the *assert* part of your test.

Once all your tests are green you might want to look into the implementation of your `Router` and see if you can use `URLComponents` inside it as well. This class is provided by Apple and is very robust.

Comment: Thes doesn't work. When I assert two urlcomponents that have the same path and parameters, I get this: XCTAssertEqual failed: ("https://www.somewebsite.com/this/path?key1=value1&key2=value2") is not equal to ("https://www.somewebsite.com/this/path?key2=value2&key1=value1")